# Button Click shouldn't stack the function it triggers but it does

Tags: javascript

I'm making an timer in Javascript which already works well the only problem is when I keep hitting the 
"Start" button it keeps stacking the count function and will count at an higher and higher speed. Tried multiple things to stop it but can't manage myself.

JS:

```
var startknop = document.getElementById("start");
var stopknop = document.getElementById("stop");
var hour = 0;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
startknop.onclick = function()
{
        intervalId = setInterval(count, 1000);
}
stopknop.onclick = function()
{
    clearInterval(intervalId);

}

    counter.innerHTML = hour + "0:" + min + "0:" + sec + "0";

    function count() {

        sec++;
        if(sec <= 9)
        {
            var seco = "0" + sec;
        }
        else
        {
            seco = sec;
        }
        if(min <= 9)
        {
            var mino = "0" + min;

        }
        else
        {
            mino = sec;
        }
        if(hour <= 9)
        {
            var houro = "0" + hour;
        }
        else
        {
            houro = hour;
        }
        if(sec == 60){
            sec = 0;
            min += 1;
        }
        if(min == 60){
            min = 0;
            hour += 1;
        }
    counter.innerHTML = houro + ":" + mino + ":" + seco;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var running = false;
startknop.onclick = function()
{
    if(!running)
    {
        running=true;
        intervalId = setInterval(count, 1000);
    }
}
```

when timer is finished set running false.

Comment: This mostly worked only needed to add `start = false;` (changed the var to start) to the other buttons Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the setInterval in an if block with a boolean to check if initialised. You are starting multiple timers, so stop only stops the last one assigned to your global variable. You could also set intervalId to -1 and do a check on it being >0, setting it back to -1 after the clearInterval call.